# Re-exporting named typescript interface throws error

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have and issue with re-exporting named typescript elements.

I have a react file similar to this:

CustomComponent/CustomComponent.tsx:

```
export interface CustomComponentProps { ... }

const CustomComponent: React.FunctionComponent<CustomComponentProps> = () => {
  ...
}
export default CustomComponent
```

CustomComponent/index.ts:

```
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent'
export { CustomComponentProps } from './CustomComponent'

export default CustomComponent
```

The error message is as follows:

> Attempted import error: 'CustomComponentProps' is not exported from './CustomComponent'.

or

```
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent'
import { CustomComponentProps } from './CustomComponent'

export default CustomComponent
export CustomComponentProps
```

Where the error message is:

> Parsing error: Declaration or statement expected

CustomComponent/index.ts when it works fine:

```
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent'
export * from './CustomComponent'

export default CustomComponent
```

What may be the cause of this error and how to fix it to use export like (or similar) to the failing example? The format of an export is important because there's a need to have a control over what's exported from `index.ts`.

Comment: `export CustomComponentProps` is invalid syntax. It has no meaning whatsoever and is purely an error.

Comment: Does it work if you do `export type { CustomComponentProps } from './CustomComponent'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to solve my issue while writing this question, so I share the solution, since I haven't found anywhere similar problem:

```
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent'
import {
  CustomComponentProps as CustomComponentPropsOriginal
} from './CustomComponent'

export default CustomComponent
export interface CustomComponentProps extends CustomComponentPropsOriginal {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert this to a type before re-exporting. This should work:

```js
export type { CustomComponentProps } from './CustomComponent'
```